# Install a python app with pipenv vs setuptools

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, pipenv, python-packaging

I've been using python with 'setuptools' for a while, but recently I've been trying to improve the way I structure a python project. This led me into 'pipenv' and I found this really interesting, as I did not enjoyed much the 'venv' way.

I've done pretty much everything I wanter with 'pipenv' but there is one crucial feature I can't match when I was using setup tools, and I started to think that maybe I am a bit confused about "what is what" and the purpose of each solution.

So I basically need to install the tools I make so other co-workers can use and I kept this straightforward using setuptools with a proper makefile:

```
install:
    pip3 install --upgrade pip
    pip3 install -r requirements.txt
    python3 setup.py install --record install.txt

test:
    python3 setup.py test

clean:
    rm -rf .eggs/ 
    rm -rf SCRT.egg-info/ 
    rm -rf build/
    rm -rf dist/
    rm -rf htmlcov/ 
    rm -rf .coverage
    rm -rf lib/__pycache__
    rm -rf operations/__pycache__

remove:
    cat install.txt | xargs rm -rf
    rm -rf install.txt


.PHONY: install
```

```
    (...)
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'tool = src.main:main'
        ]
    }
    (...)
```

and with this solution and a proper setup.py I could have a script in my bin folder and run it as if it was a program.

However, I can't find anything like this with pipenv that targets the virvual environment that pipenv creates, without using "pipenv run 'target'".
The idea is to keep it simple for the other users and just make a quick install and use.

Any suggestions on how to approach this solution?

Comment: pipenv is supposed to manage your dependencies, i.e. install them in a virtualenv. You could consider it a replacement for pip not for setuptools. If you need to install an executable you have to either use setuptools or flit.